# What is the double-dot operator (..) in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, operator-keyword

I'm doing some work with the Parser API in Spidermonkey. [The docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SpiderMonkey/Parser_API#Miscellaneous) show that there's a binary operator `..`. Anybody have *any* idea what this is/does? I'd love to know. I've never seen it before. If I were forced to guess, I'd have to say it's something with E4X, but that's only because I know nothing about E4X.

Comment: two lines below the section in the linked doc with the .. says "Note: the .. operator is E4X-specific."

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is an E4X operator.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide:Processing_XML_with_E4X:

> While the . operator accesses direct children of the given node, the .. operator accesses all children no matter how deeply nested:

Comment: Since the link is dead: https://web.archive.org/web/20210514140120/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/E4X/Processing_XML_with_E4X

Answer (score 50):

Not to be confused with the decimal point and dot:

```
var val= 1000..toExponential()
```

Comment: This confused me for some time - it seemed to have the same effect as `(1000).method()` so I thought it was a special operator. The decimal didn't occur to me. Nice!

Answer (score 17):

Something like:

```
255..toString(16);
```

First dot is actually a decimal point, just let JavaScript Compiler know the second dot wants to invoke property or method. And `255.toString(16)` makes JavaScript Compiler confused(identifier starts immediately after decimal numeric literal).

Comment: Tip: the `.` operator has higher precedence than unary `-` or unary `+`, which convert their operands to `Number`.  `typeof(-255..toString())` is `'number'`. That is, it is parsed as if it were `typeof(-(255..toString()))`, effectively `typeof(-(Number(255.toString())))`.

Answer (score 5):

It is indeed E4X. It does the same thing as the single dot operator, which selects children, but it selects all descendants. (It's by analogy with XPath's `/` operator selecting children of an element that match the selector and `//` selecting all descendants that match the selector.)