# Strange tokens in javascript

Tags: javascript

There are several tokens in [this page](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/js/language/js20-1999-02-18/tokens.html) that I have no idea what are used for in Javascript. Those are "->", "::", "..", "...". What are they used for? Or are they just some kind of vestigial feature that never got mainstream?

Comment: [What is the double-dot operator (..) in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4211037/1402846).

Comment: Note that it's a very old draft for JavaScript 2.0, not the current version.

Comment: Here's [a more recent list of operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators)

Comment: [What does ‘::’ (double colon) do in javascript for events?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5715239/1402846).

Comment: None of these punctuators appear on page 19 of the more recent [ECMA-262 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf).

Comment: Thanks everybody for pointing me to the ECMA standard!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the February 1999 Draft of JavaScript 2.0! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators is a nice handy list from the new spec.

JavaScript is really called ECMAScript now, and it's spec is here: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf.

Comment: Note that I've made this community wiki as it's just formalising the answers from above.