# why does 1..toString() work and return "1" but 1.toSring() cause an syntax error?

Tags: javascript

I know 1 is not an object, but when I type `1..toString()`, it returns "1" in the console. Why is that?

[image]

Comment: It's a frequent question, let's look for the proper QA for closing...

Comment: @Loaf You should write this as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: This question has a lot of good explanations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211037/what-is-the-double-dot-operator-in-javascript

Comment: 1..toString is not the double dot operator: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4211641/735926

Comment: `1 .toString()` is a fun alternative.

Comment: @Mouser Your comment is very very wrong

Comment: If the question is why you can access properties on primitive values, see [Does javascript autobox?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17216847/218196)

Comment: @Mouser - If that was true, you wouldn't be able to add numbers as it would do string concatenation.

Comment: @DanPrince its fun and highly error prone

Comment: @leo_ap Anyone who writes `1 .toString()` rather than `'1'` deserves to have errors.

Comment: @DanPrince I don't discuss that :)

Answer (score 6):

Because the JavaScript parser assumes that `1.` must be followed only by one or more digits to represent a float number. Using parentheses works: `(1).toString()`.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is interpreting `1.` as the number. When you have `1.toString()`, it is the same as saying `(1.)toString()`. Therefore `1..toString()` is the same as `(1.).toString()`

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the below works is:

```
1..toString()
```

The `1..` is considered as a floating point number. The console expects something like:

```
1.0
1.5
```

Or something. If you are giving something like:

```
1.toString();
```

The above is not a valid number. That's the reason. So to make the above work, you need a parenthesis to tell that the number is completed:

```
(1).toString();
```